# How to remove jmx-console.war file in jboss-as-4.3

Tags: java, jboss, jms

I am using jboss-as-4.3 in production so i need to remove the jmx-console.war file

i found some related jms file in my deployee.

```
C:\jboss-as-4.3\server\production\deploy\jmx-console.war 

C:\jboss-as-4.3\server\production\deploy\jmx-invoker-service.xml 

C:\jboss-as-4.3\server\production\deploy\jms-ra.rar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a wiki page on trimming the jboss at https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss6xTuningSlimming. But that is on 6.x. I guess a lot of it may apply to 4.3 as well.

Comment: Thanx @suresh .in need to remove all deploye folders files which are not requires to start jboss server .can you please tel me how to proced.

Comment: Is there a specific deployment that you are looking to remove besides the jmx-console? Are you using the default or the full version of deployment?

Answer (score 0):

The second two are JMS so you might want to leave those, but deleting the first one will disable jmx-console
 It is a useful tool though .. have you considered securing It?

Nag;

It's impossible to say what you should remove or keep without knowing the details of your application. I would follow the link suggested by Suresh and keep in mind that some dependencies may not be obvious. For example, various services like EJB3 depend on **jboss-aop-jdk50.deployer**.

Cheers.

Comment: thanx Nicholas,but i was maintain secured level in my application ,i thought that i don't need of jmx-console. i need to clear the all deploy application  which of not required to start the jboss...can you please tell me which of required and not required for startup jboss?

Comment: jboss-as-4.3 deploye folder consists of uuid-key-generator.sar,snmp-adaptor.sar,juddi-service.sar,jmx-console.war,jbossws.sar,jboss-web-cluster.sar,jboss-web.deployer,jboss-messaging.sar,jboss-bean.deployer,jboss-aop-jdk50.deployer,httpha-invoker.sar,ejb3.deployer,deploy.last    ...can you please give me which one is not required to stat the jboss server ?